# Compiling at run time in Visual C#

Tags: c#, string, properties, compilation

I'm learning compiling a file at run time using `CSharpCodeProvider`, `CompilerParameters`, `CompilerResults` and such.

I was able to get the content of a string **through** a method.

```
public static string Test()    //This is in the file to be compiled.
{
    return "This is a test string!";
}
```

and using

```
MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Test");    //This is in the main program.
//program is a Assembly Type generated in another part of the program.
str=main.Invoke(null, null).ToString();
```

to get the string.

How can I get the string directly? Such as,

```
public string str="This is a test string!";    //This is in the file to be compiled.
```

I had tried making the string a property and use `GetProperty("str");`, but all it get is the **name** of the property, eg. **str**, I don't know how to get the **content** of the string, eg. **This is a test string!**.

Below are the codes:

```
using System.IO;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MudOS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

            string str = File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\MudLib\Test.c");
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, str);

            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Compiling error!");
                return;
            }
            Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
            Type program = assembly.GetType("MudOS.Test");
            MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Test");
            resultString=main.Invoke(null, null).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(resultString);

            PropertyInfo pinfo = program.GetProperty("str");
            MessageBox.Show(pinfo.Name.ToString());
            //I want the CONTENT of the string, not the NAME.
        }
    }
}
```

And the following are the file to be compiled at run time: Test.c

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MudOS
{
    class Test
    {
        public string testStr="This is a test string!";
        //I would like to know if it's possible to get this string directly.

        public string str
        {
            get{ return "This is a test string!"; }
            //I was unable to get this content.
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
        }

        public static string Test()
        {
            return "This is a test string!";
            //I was able to get this content just fine.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Will do! Updating!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
program.getField("testStr").getValue(null).
```

Try this method after obtaining Type from assembly.

Comment: Thank you! I had changed the accepted answer to yours! But please DO delete the other answers! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var type = typeof(MethodContainer);
            var method = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
            var mc = new MethodContainer();
            string result = (string)method.Invoke(mc, null);
            Console.WriteLine(result); //Output: This is a test
        }
    }

    public class MethodContainer
    {
        public string MyMethod()
        {
            return "This is a test";
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

You must obtain the type (`typeof(Your_Clas)`) of your class, and then obtain the method using `GetMethod()`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("MyMethod");
            string result = (string)method.Invoke(null, null);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }

        public static string MyMethod()
        {
            return "LOL";
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but  I already state that I was already able to get the string **through** the method. I would like to learn how to get the string **directly**. Thank you very much!

Comment: That was just like the part of the code I had just provided! >"<  Is it impossible to get the string through a **property** or **directly**!?

Comment: @Pikachu620 You mean: `string test = MyMethod()`?

Comment: I mean, `string test = "This is a test string!";` Is it possible!? Or calling through a method is the only way!?

Comment: @Pikachu620 Yes, Is possible using `string test = "This is a test string!";` and calling through a method, two ways are possible

Comment: No no no... what I meant is... getting the string directly **from** the file to be compiled! Geez! This is so hard to explain!!! >"<

Comment: @Pikachu620 Let's see if I understood, what you want is to get the content **public string testStr="This is a test string!"**; of this file? `@ "\ MudLib \ Test.c`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172367/discussion-between-pikachu620-and-hector-manuel-martinez-duran).